# A twice differentiable function satisfying a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification, sturm-liouville

The question is :

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable function satisfying

$f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x), x\in \mathbb{R} $ where $g(x) \ge 0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Which of the following is\are true?

$(1)$ If $f(0)=f'(0)=1$ , then $f(3)\lt 3$

$(2)$ If $f(0)=f'(0)=2$ , then $f(4)\lt 4$

$(3)$ If $f(0)=f'(0)=3$ , then $f(3)=5$

$(4)$ If $f(0)=f'(0)=3$ , then $f(3)=6$

My thoughts:-

I will first discuss about $(3)$ and $(4)$

Let $g(x)=0$

Then with some computation , we can show

$f(x)=3(\sin x+\cos x)$ as a suitable candidate to discard $(3)$ and $(4)$

Here , for option $(3)$

$f(3)=5$

$\Rightarrow \sin 3+\cos 3=\frac 53$

On squaring both sides

$1+\sin 6=\frac{25}9$

$\sin 6=\frac {16}9 \gt 1$, a contradiction

Similarly $f(3)= 6$ will give the contradiction

$\sin 3+\cos 3=2$ ( implying $\sin 3=\cos 3=1$ which is an impossibility) .

Thus we are left with $(1)$ and $(2)$

Note:A slight variant of the above example satisfies the condition in $(1)$ and $(2)$

I tried with simple examples like $g(x)=1 $ and $f(x)=x$ or like quadratics but couldn't reach conclusions .

Please help with the options $(1)$ and $(2)$ . Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the energy function $E=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}E=2f'(x)(f''(x)+f(x))=-2xg(x)f'(x)^2
$$
so that $E$ is falling along solutions. As far as I can see this implies that 1) and 2) are true.

In 1) $f(x)\le\sqrt{E(x)}\le\sqrt{E(0)}=\sqrt2<3$ and similarly in 2) $f(x)\le\sqrt8<4$. The same way you get in 3) and 4) $f(x)\le\sqrt{18}<5$, so that the given values can never be reached.

Comment: I realised that I misunderstood your answer. Can you please clarify what do you mean by "E is falling along solutions "? Are you saying that $\frac {dE}{dt} \le 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I see I was somewhat mixing the variable names, corrected.